# WooCommerce NGINX caching and wc-session cookie add to cart issue

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

I am trying to install my WooCommerce v3.4 site to new VPS server built with Ubuntu 18.04 , PHP7.1 , and NGINX. My problem with WooCommerce session and cookie. cookies  are not separate for different user. if someone add product or update cart it added for all user.

here is my server conf file please help me to fix this issue.

```
server {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        client_max_body_size 64m;


        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }



        set $skip_cache 0;
        if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }
        if ($query_string != "") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }
        if ($request_uri ~* "(/shop.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*|/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }
        if ( $arg_add-to-cart != "" ) { 
          set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ( $cookie_woocommerce_items_in_cart ) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }   


        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_cache cachezone;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60s;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 60s;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

            set $rt_session "";
            if ($http_cookie ~* "wc_session_cookie_[^=]*=([^%]+)%7C") {
                set $rt_session wc_session_cookie_$1;
            }

            if ($skip_cache = 0 ) {
                more_clear_headers "Set-Cookie*";
                set $rt_session "";
            }
        }




        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
            root /usr/share/;
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
                deny all;
            }

        location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          }
        }


        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  1100;
        gzip_buffers  4 32k;
        gzip_types    text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
        gzip_vary on;

}
```

Comment: Hello, did you fix this and how? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No ! failed to solve it thats why i am using Apache instead of NGINX

Answer (score 4):

we fixed already.

The problem is the cache files contains some headers, including "Set-Cookie" so if you check your NGINX cache files you might find the `wc_session_cookie_` cookie there.

What we did to resolved it was to exclude the cookie headers with this code:

```
if( $skip_cache = 0 ) {
   more_clear_headers "Set-Cookie";
}
```

So now every user session is independent, but now we are facing another issue where a WC coupon is creating duplicated sessions, but we're fixing it by using JS.

Hope you can find this useful.

You can find resources here:

https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_headers

https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_input_headers

Comment: Hello @RoelMagdaleno, thanks for the answer, I had the exact same issue. So some user would get other users interface/authorization cause they were receiving a cached header/cookie.
Did you used "more_clear_input_headers" ? I'm wondering if I should use it, as only GET/HEAD are cached by Fastcgi actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Nginx with fast_cgi caching and Woocommerce.. you can avoid session cart collision by trying this:

```
    set $rt_session "";

    if ($http_cookie ~* "wp_woocommerce_session_[^=]*=([^%]+)%7C") {
                set $rt_session wp_woocommerce_session_$1;
        }   

    if ($skip_cache = 0 ) {
        more_clear_headers "Set-Cookie*";
        set $rt_session "";
    }

        fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$rt_session";
```

More on that here:
https://gist.github.com/khalilgharbaoui/f06edbd7f7fcfbfe58935c295e128644  << Full code here
https://easyengine.io/tutorials/wordpress/woocommerce-window-shopping-caching-technique/
https://gist.github.com/rahul286/dc64ae84c97868b862c4#file-woo-nginx-conf